# AsyncTask not called from TimerTask android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler, timertask

I am developing the project which continuously get datas from server at 30secs interval.So I used Handler with Timer and called Asynctask.

But my asynctask not called.This is my code,

```
      final Handler handler;
         handler = new Handler();
           timer = new Timer();
          TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask()
          {       
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  handler.post(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {       
                          try
                          {

                              System.out.println("I am xxx");
                              LiveTrack myActivity = new LiveTrack();
                              AsyncTask<String, String, String> task = myActivity.new VehiclePath();
                                task.execute();




                          } 
                          catch (Exception e) 
                          {

                          }
                      }
                  });
              }
          };
          timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 30000);
```

Can anyone guide me why I am facing this?

Comment: No enclosing instance of type LiveTrack is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type LiveTrack (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of LiveTrack). For this I get instance of my class

Comment: What's LiveTrack? Is it an `Activity`, or is it just poorly named?

Comment: If it's a proper `Activity`, you know you can't just instantiate that, right?

Comment: yeah you are right...but I am getting that error when trying to call asyntask

Comment: What error? You didn't post an error, you just said your `AsyncTask` isn't called. My guess is that it's not called, because the app can't get past the instantiation of an `Activity`. Make your `AsyncTask` static, or better yet, pull it out of the `Activity` class altogether.

Comment: When I call my asynctask outside of timer It works fine.When I am trying to call it inside of the timer it does not even gets call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create an AsyncTask from within a TimerTask because it runs on a spawned thread, i.e. 
not the UI thread).

**AsynTasks must be created and execute()-ed only on the UI thread.**

Instead, use an Executor for the background processing and call [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) when it is time to update the UI.

```
 ExecutorService executorPool =  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

 executorPool.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do background processing here <------------------

        myActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                   // update ui here <--------------------
              }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: comment // update ui here is the place where I call asynctask right?

Comment: @Gilad Haimov I have a similar use case.  Is the code to update the ui within "myActivity.runOnUiThread..." always guaranteed to run only after the background code has completely finished executing?